# Why are my privates accessible?

Tags: c#, .net, oop

I have the following code:

```
public class PersonInitializer
{
    private Person _person;

    public static Person LoadFromFile(string path)
    {
        PersonInitializer x = new PersonInitializer();

        Person p = x._person; //Why am I accessible?

        return x.LoadFromFile(); //Sure.

    }

    public Person LoadFromFile(string path)
    {

    }
}
```

Why is _`person` accessible from `x` even if it is `private`? What can I do to "protect" _person?

Comment: very funny question title if you are immature and childish like me.

Comment: Peter, I edited the question so no more funny jokes on that ;)

Comment: @Peter: I thought it would be funny! It is intentional, glad you liked it. :)

Comment: Check for a MissingTrousers compiler warning...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are private fields private to the type, not the instance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983553/why-are-private-fields-private-to-the-type-not-the-instance)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are accessing it from a member function.
If you want to prevent access from that particular function, you may want to move that static function to  a new class.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 12):

It is accessible, because you are the class it is defined in!

Access modifiers apply to classes, not to instances of a class. That means, an instance of class A has access to all private members of another instance of class A.

I assume, you agree with me, that this is ok:

```
var p = this._person;
```

But what about this:

```
public void DoSomething(PersonInitializer personInitializer)
{
    var p = personInitializer._person;
}
```

According to your assumption, this code would be valid depending on the input.
Example:

```
DoSomething(this); // ok
DoSomething(other); // not ok
```

This makes no sense :-)

Comment: Scope based on instances of a class does make sence, Effel does it.   It just lost out to the C++ mindset that lead to C# scopeing based on classes.

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/st6sy9xe.aspx):

> Private members are accessible only
>   within the body of the class or the
>   struct in which they are declared.

Since `LoadFromFile` is within the body of the class where `_person` is declared, it has access to it. There's nothing you can do about that, since

> Private access is the least
>   permissive access level.

Answer (score 0):

Private variable's/references are accessible only in the class in which they are defined.
Since in you case, the reference `Person _person;` is defined in the same class from where you are accessing it, it is accessible.

Answer (score 0):

In C# (and Jave, C++) the scope of a field is based on the class, so **all instances of the class** can access private members of **other instances of the same class**.

In languages like [Eiffel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_%28programming_language%29#Scoping) (and Smalltalk) the scope of a field is based on the **instance**, so a private field can **only be access by the same instance**.   The Eiffel method may be better, but C++ won the hearts and minds of most programmer, hence very few people question “class based scopeing”

Comment: Ian, you cannot make something so private that not even the same class can use it, sorry but the visibility accessor **secret** was not invented yet, so you can use **private** and this means from other classes you cannot see and use private members.