# Why private field is accessible?

Tags: .net, oop, static

C#. Why private field is accessible ?

```
internal class MyClass
{
   private int someInt;

   public static StaticMethod() 
   {
      new MyClass().someInt = 3;
   }
}
```

Comment: You need to read an introductory article about OOP.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why are my privates accessible?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244997/why-are-my-privates-accessible)

Comment: If it wasn't accessible by the methods of the class, what purpose would it serve?

Comment: I think you should read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

Answer (score 4):

It is accessible by all instances of **the same class**.

The accessibility is for the *class*, not per instance.

Comment: or, in this case, a static method of this class.

Comment: @Penfold - What do you mean? It is in a static method, but the value is applied to a new instance.

Comment: yes, but it's accessible from the static method. You said it is only accessible by instances of the same class. It's not accessible from instances of other classes, or from static methods of other classes.

Comment: @Penfold - I still don't follow. `new MyClass()` is a new instance of the class. Calling `.someInt` on that is calling it on an instance of the class. That the new instance is initialized inside of a static method is neither here nor there.

Comment: It's exactly what we're talking about.  If you had the same line `new MyClass().someInt = 3` in a static method of another class, or a non-static method of another class, it wouldn't work.  That's what you meant when you said "accessible by all instances of the same class", and I expanded that to also include static methods **of the same class**.